# MacBook Pro and external monitor compatibility

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dvi, vga

I just bought my first Mac (to learn to build apps!). I have the June 2012 non-retina display 15 inch MacBook Pro. Does **any** 16x10 aspect ratio montior technically work (monitor with VGA and DVI jacks)?

Comment: You will be hard pressed to find a monitor that will not work with the current thunderbolt ports. Since any Mini DisplayPort adapter will work you can start with VGA and work up to DVI/HDMI as well as other more exotic displays with more expensive adapters if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apple 15" MacBook Pro specification about Graphics and Video Support says:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up
>   to two external displays, at millions of colors Thunderbolt digital
>   video output
>
> Native Mini DisplayPort output DVI output using Mini DisplayPort to
>   DVI Adapter (sold separately) VGA output using Mini DisplayPort to VGA
>   Adapter (sold separately) Dual-link DVI output using Mini DisplayPort
>   to Dual-Link DVI Adapter (sold separately)

Answer (score 2):

I have a late 2011 15 inch MBP and have successfully used Thunderbolt adaptors to connect to monitors via DVI and TV via HDMI with excellent results. You don't need a 16:10 screen - the display will adapt to various screen dimensions.

I think you can plug just about anything in with a very high chance of success.